# Adding multiple texts to AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios, swift3, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, catextlayer

I am composing a video using AVMutableComposition. I need to add text overlay at different time intervals. i,e.

1. display string "abc" from 0sec to 2sec hide afterwards
2. display string "xyz" from 1sec to 1.5sec hide afterwards
3. display string "qwe" from 2sec to 5sec

I am using the below code to add text overlay but its static and stays through out the video.

```
let parentLayer = CALayer()
parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
let videoLayer = CALayer()
videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

let subtitleText = CATextLayer()
subtitleText.font = font
subtitleText.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: size.width, height: 50)
subtitleText.string = "hhh"
subtitleText.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
subtitleText.foregroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
subtitleText.displayIfNeeded()


parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
parentLayer.addSublayer(subtitleText)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs answer for this, am sorry I couldn't find a direct solution, so i did a costly work around.

- Trim your video according to your text's time ranges
- Add text to the trimmed videos
- And merge those pieces back

Answer (score 0):

Use **CABasicAnimation** on **CALayer** to specify presentation time range in **AVMutableComposition**:

```
/// Build animation for property
/// - keyPath: animatable property key path
/// - fromValue: value to animate from, previous is used for `nil`
/// - toValue: value to animate to
/// - atTime: start time in seconds
/// - duration: animation duration
func animate(_ keyPath: String, fromValue: Any? = nil, toValue: Any?, atTime: CFTimeInterval = 0.0, duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.0) -> CABasicAnimation {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.fromValue = fromValue
    animation.toValue = toValue
    animation.beginTime = atTime
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false // to keep animated value after animation finished
    animation.fillMode = .forwards
    return animation
}
```

To present **CATextLayer** from *1.5* to *3.0* sec use:

```
subtitleText.opacity = 0.0
subtitleText.add(animate("opacity", toValue: 1.0, atTime: 1.5), forKey: "animateFadeIn")
subtitleText.add(animate("opacity", toValue: 0.0, atTime: 3.0), forKey: "animateFadeOut")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).